# How to make interact parameters visible while we type them?

Tags: tcl, expect

The following code works fine. When I type 'aaa', the interact session gets closed.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require Expect
log_user 1
spawn su
expect "ssword:"
send "root\n"

interact "abcdefgh" return
```

When I start typing `abc...`, it is not visible at the terminal. If it happens to be the functionality of interact, is there any other way to view what I am typing ?

Example.

I type `a` in the device , it is not visible . type, `abcdefg` , these are also not visible.But when I type 'abcdefgh' , not visible but interact ends.

If I type `a` and then `z` , it is visible since the pattern `abcdefgh` not match.
This will irritate us when we dont intent to type `abcdefgh`

kindly ask me if you dont understand what I am asking.

Comment: I believe you need to send with \r instead of \n. Furthermore, the interact command does not take any parameter.

Comment: @HaiVu Thank you very much hai vu. \r works instead of \n. Could you please give me answer for the second question ???

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Absolutely .

Answer (score 1):

"I believe you need to send with \r instead of \n. Furthermore, the interact command does not take any parameter."

According to Johannes Kuhn, `interact` does take parameter. I believe the doc I read was either old, or does not mention this.

As for the second question, I am still looking at the book and digging through old codes for answer. I will update my answer when found.